# react-native error:FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher; Process: com.tigergameapp, PID: 23377; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env

Tags: react-native, out-of-memory, okhttp, dispatcher

i am using react-native to creat an app but get an error about okHttp Dispatcher and really need help.

i'have tried to find some solutions and which told me to change the .string() method which can be used only once, but i never use this method.

```
PS G:\RN1workspace\TigerGameApp> adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of crash
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.tigergameapp, PID: 23377
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put(ConnectionPool.java:135)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$1.put(OkHttpClient.java:149)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
08-16 19:27:42.223 23377 29132 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
```

Comment: can you debug and know when it's occurring?

Comment: i'have already get an apk and installed in my smart phone and the application Flash, then i use command： adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S。then i get the error。

Answer (score 0):

now i solved the error, the reason is that i use the function: this.timer = setInterval(//...);
and i did not clear it. so add the following code would solve the error:
this.timer && clearInterval(this.timer);

thanks for everyone.